S3 object or even bucket that can only be queried using range requests
I have some objects that are very large and stored in various duckdb database's. I would like to pass a presigned URL to authenticated clients to access this data. I've built a web app that allows users to query this in R, Python, SQL, takes care of auth, sends requests as range requests... so on.
I want the client to only be able to query these files not download the entire file. What is the path of least resistance to do this?
I was hoping there would be some bucket or individual object policy that I can assign to disallow GET requests for full download but allow for GET HTTP Range requests. I can't find any documentation about this though, or any docs for types of policies I can attach (like a comprehensive list). Clearly I'm not familiar with this.
Can think of a couple workarounds, but they probably aren't good

Short presigned URL
Use Lambda (S3 Object Lambda or some other custom Lambda)
Some custom requirements in presigned URL?

I feel like some policy exists for this though.

Nope, this isn't possible. You can specify a Range as part of a GET request, but you can't enforce its use. You could probably provide a pre-signed URL with the range hard-coded into it. Alternatively, taking a completely different approach, you could consider using Amazon Athena to query objects in S3 without having to download any data -- just send SQL and get back the results. Same thing for S3 Select (which only does one file at a time).

@JohnRotenstein thanks for the answer! Ya I'm trying to avoid additional cost. For a little more context this web app and the querying to S3 is all compiled in a WASM app. Trying to push all the compute to the client to avoid cost and also not have to deal with headache of running user code on a server / serverless function. I'll look into your suggestions above a little more, as I've yet to use them, but maybe I can figure out a safe cost effective way.
